# Matrix duplicate extraction

Tags: java

I have 200 columns and 80,000 rows of data.

Rows contain duplicate data.

I want to extract only the unique data from the duplicated data in the row, but leave only the maximum value in the column among the duplicated rows.

How can I do it?

ex)
before

```
    s1  s2  s3  .. s200
r1   0   0   4  ..    5
r1   3   0   1  ..    0
r2   2   0   0  ..    1
r3   0   7   0  ..    8 
r3   0   9   6  ..   17
r3   0   0   0  ..   12
```

after

```
    s1  s2  s3  ..  s200
r1   3   0   4  ..     5  
r2   2   0   0  ..     1 
r3   0   9   6   ..   17
```

thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us your work. It is expected that you tried to solve it first by yourself

Comment: Do the rows contain some `id` column which allows to group by this column (e.g. `r1`, `r3` in the first column)?

Answer (score 0):

From the given example it is possible to assume that the matrix contains a column identifying the row (rowId).

Then this task can be resolved using Stream API:

1. build a map using `Collectors.toMap`
2. use a rowId column as a key, the entire row (`int[]`) is a value
3. implement merge function for the values to keep the max values

```java
static int[][] filterMatrix(int[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                     a -> a[0], // assuming the first column holds rowId
                     a -> a, 
                     (a1, a2) -> IntStream.range(0, a1.length)
                                          .map(i -> Math.max(a1[i], a2[i]))
                                          .toArray()
                 ))
                 .values()
                 .stream()  // Stream<int[]> - stream of rows
                 .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Test (abbreviated):

```java
int[][] m = new int[][] {
    {1, 0, 0,  4,  5},
    {1, 3, 0,  1,  0},
    {2, 2, 0,  1,  1},
    {3, 0, 7,  1,  8},
    {3, 0, 6,  9, 17},
    {3, 0, 0, 12,  1},
};

int[][] max = filterMatrix(m);

for (int[] r : max) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 0, 4, 5]
[2, 2, 0, 1, 1]
[3, 0, 7, 12, 17]
```